# "Could not load file or assembly Kitware.VTK" when using x64 version of Kitware.VTK

Tags: c#, wpf, vtk

I'm using Kitware.VTK x86 since I started using this library because I've never been able to make the x64 version works. Now I'd like to understand why.

With the x64 version, as soon as I start using a VTK class, I get the following error:

[image]

Sorry for french langage, the error is simply "Could not load file or assembly Kitware.VTK"

Here is the only code I wrote to rise this exception:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RenderWindowControl renderer = new RenderWindowControl();
    }
```

Again, everything works well with x86 version. But I'm starting to have other problems later in my code with this library, so in a fit of despair, I just hope that being able to switch to the x64 version will fix all my problems !

**Edit**:

In the InnerException details there's also this error : "Trying to load an incorrect format program."

Comment: Is your main application targeted to `Any CPU` or `x86`?

Comment: Could you check if you have the right `processorArchitecture` value in your (csproj) project `Reference`s (for these assemblies)?

Comment: sorry but where do I find that?

Comment: Open the csproj file for the main application (or wherever you have a reference to these VTK assemblies) in a notepad. Search for `<Reference` elements in that file, and see if you have `processorArchitecture` value set to `x64` for these VTK references.

Comment: Oh yes, it is set to AMD64

Comment: I guess, that's probably right.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sthotakura, I've been looking to the value of the active plateforme of the application, which was set to Any CPU.
I tried to set it to x64, and it's working well.

I still don't understand why I had to do this, but at least it's working..